# Specify a httpGet and exec handler in a liveness/readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have multiple handlers in a container probe ? 
Something like

```
livenessProbe: {
     httpGet: {
         path: "/ping",
         port: 9099
     },
     exec: {
         command: [
             "verify-correctness.sh",
         ]
     }
 }
```

---

Update:

At Kube 1.6x `kubectl apply` for a config like this returns

```
spec.template.spec.containers[0].livenessProbe.httpGet: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 handler type
```

So maybe not supported ?

---

Update 2:

After [Ara Pulido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261781/5771861)'s answer I combined the httpGet into the command like this:

```
 "livenessProbe": {
             "exec": {
                "command": [
                   "sh",
                   "-c",
                   "reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:9099/ping); if [ \"$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi; verify-correctness.sh;"
                ]
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37218) about this, which contains several workarounds people use.